# Smooth scroll working for navbar, but not other elements (arrows etc)

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, scroll

I have a Rails application that uses a jQuery smooth scrolling function.  The smooth scroll works for the navbar links, but not for the 'scroll down' arrow or 'back to top' arrow.  I've tried adding a script tag to implement the behavior directly on the element, but no luck.  Any recommendations are appreciated!

Here is the scroll function -

```js
// Select all links with hashes
$('a[href*="#"]')
  // Remove links that don't actually link to anything
  .not('[href="#"]')
  .not('[href="#0"]')
  .click(function(event) {
    // On-page links
    if (
      location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') 
      && 
      location.hostname == this.hostname
    ) {
      // Figure out element to scroll to
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
      // Does a scroll target exist?
      if (target.length) {
        // Only prevent default if animation is actually gonna happen
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000, function() {
          // Callback after animation
          // Must change focus!
          var $target = $(target);
          $target.focus();
          if ($target.is(":focus")) { // Checking if the target was focused
            return false;
          } else {
            $target.attr('tabindex','-1'); // Adding tabindex for elements not focusable
            $target.focus(); // Set focus again
          };
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

Here is the block containing the down arrow.  The parens with (some text here) are not in my actual code, I just changed it for S/O. -

```html
<div class="typebox" style="min-height: 119px;">
   <div id="typed-strings">
   <h3 class="type-active"><strong style="font-size: 20px; line-height: 1.5em;"> (some text here) <br> (some more text here) &nbsp; <br><br><a href="#web-apps"><%= image_tag "down-arrow.png", class: "down-arrow"%></a></strong></h3>
  </div> 
  <span id="typed"></span> 
  <br />
 </div>
```

Comment: Is the click triggering the callback? Did you check if `target` is found on that function? put a breakpoint on the line `if (target.length)` and you can inspect the `target` variable. Can you create a codepen/jsfiddle to reproduce the problem?

Comment: I'm not super familiar with breakpoints yet, but here's a link to my site.  www.justincefai.co

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot find your code on the link, but seeing your website I can think of a few things:

1) your down arrow is not there when you set the click callback, it's added later with that typed effect so the click callback is not set on that A tag. I guess the library you used for that has some event to let you know that the effect is finished, then you can set the callback for that A tag

2) the back to top arrow has `href="#"` which is explicittly NOT selected for the click function with the line `.not('[href="#"]')`, I'm guessing you copied the function from somewhere else, you can add an id after the href for that back to top A tag and add an element wit that ID at the top of the site

---

EDIT: to fix the down arrow event listener, I would do this:

1st, move the function outside the parameters

```
function scroll_to_hash(event) {
  // On-page links
  if (
    location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') 
    && 
    location.hostname == this.hostname
  ) {
    // Figure out element to scroll to
    var target = $(this.hash);
    target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
    // Does a scroll target exist?
    if (target.length) {
      // Only prevent default if animation is actually gonna happen
      event.preventDefault();
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: target.offset().top
      }, 1000, function() {
        // Callback after animation
        // Must change focus!
        var $target = $(target);
        $target.focus();
        if ($target.is(":focus")) { // Checking if the target was focused
          return false;
        } else {
          $target.attr('tabindex','-1'); // Adding tabindex for elements not focusable
          $target.focus(); // Set focus again
        };
      });
    }
  }
}

// Select all links with hashes
$('a[href*="#"]')
  // Remove links that don't actually link to anything
  .not('[href="#"]')
  .not('[href="#0"]')
  .click(scroll_to_hash);
```

2nd, I'm guessing you are using Typed.js, you have an `onComplete` callback https://mattboldt.com/typed.js/docs/, you can then set the click event for the down arrow on that callback on the options when you initialize the plugin

```
onComplete: function(self) {
  $('a[href="#web-apps"]').click(scroll_to_hash)
}
```

Comment: Nice, thanks for that!  Super easy fix for the back to top arrow.  However, I don't quite follow how I would go about setting the callback for the down arrow.

Comment: Yeah exactly, it's Typed.js.  Ok, so the smooth scroll is working now (thanks!), but the typed.js behavior has stopped working.  I'm going to continue to play around with it, but if you have any ideas I'm down to hear them!

Comment: I found this thread where he seems to be addressing a similar issue, but the fix he recommends gives me the same error I was getting before.    https://github.com/mattboldt/typed.js/issues/341

Comment: Add your current code to the question, I'm not sure what it looks right now, show the part where you initialize the Typed function.

Comment: Here you go, at the bottom of the file in the script tag.   https://gist.github.com/cefaijustin/b464ea64610b7cb63db8f56b4b51a173

Comment: Do you see any error on the console? the las ";" at the end of the onComplete function doesn't look right but I guess it should show some error if it's an invalid sintax.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183451/discussion-between-justin-cefai-and-arieljuod).